# Number of consecutive digits in a column string

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to count the number of consecutive digits appear in a string column, let me give an example to illustrate better what i am trying to do. If i have table called `email`

```
email
lucas1234@gmail.com
fer12@gmail.com
lupal@gmail.com
carlos1perez222@gmail.com
```

my expected output would be

```
                    email  count_cons_digits
      lucas1234@gmail.com                  4
          fer12@gmail.com                  2
          lupal@gmail.com                  0
carlos1perez222@gmail.com                  3
```

Comment: what count you are looking for in case of `carlos123perez2222@gmail.com `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex replacement with length trick:

```sql
SELECT email,
       LENGTH(email) - LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(email, '[0-9]{2,}', '')) AS count_cons_digits
FROM yourTable;
```

Note that this answer assumes that there would be at most one segment of a given email string having continuous digits.  If not, and there could be more than one, then you would need to define what happens in that case.

Comment: Thanks! but can be that this is just counting the number of digits in a string and not the consecutive number of digits in a string ?

Comment: I edited my answer so that it only matches "groups" of numbers, with a group being defined as two or more numbers.