# max consecutive digits in a string

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to count the number of MAX consecutive digits that appear in a string column, let me give an example to illustrate better what I am trying to do. If I have a table called `email`

```
email
lucas1234@gmail.com
fer12@gmail.com
lupal@gmail.com
carlos1perez222@gmail.com
carlos11perez222@gmail.com
lucila1@gmail.com
```

my expected output would be

```
                    email  count_cons_digits
      lucas1234@gmail.com                  4
          fer12@gmail.com                  2
          lupal@gmail.com                  0
carlos1perez222@gmail.com                  3
```

carlos11perez222@gmail.com                  3
lucila1@gmail.com                  1

Check that this question is very similar to :
[Number of consecutive digits in a column string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72696780/number-of-consecutive-digits-in-a-column-string)

but the only difference is that the function from the results is not contemplating cases with only one digit in the email (like lucila1@gmail.com). In this case, the expected result should be 1 but the proposed function is giving 0. And also whenever the email contains "two sections" of consecutive digits (carlos11perez222@gmail.com). In this case, the expected output is to be 3 but is given 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select *, 
  ifnull((select length(digits) len
    from unnest(regexp_extract_all(email, r'\d+')) digits
    order by len desc 
    limit 1
  ), 0) as count_cons_digits
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may also try this approach using regex:

```sql
WITH email AS
(SELECT 'lucas1234@gmail.com' mail,
UNION ALL SELECT 'fer12@gmail.com',
UNION ALL SELECT 'lupal@gmail.com',
UNION ALL SELECT 'carlos1perez222@gmail.com',
UNION ALL SELECT 'carlos11perez222@gmail.com',
UNION ALL SELECT 'lucila1@gmail.com')

SELECT email,
(LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(email.mail, r'[A-Za-z]+\d+[A-Za-z]+', ''),r'[A-Za-z.@]+',''))) AS count_cons_digits,
FROM email;
```

Output:
[image]